# .htaccess QUERY_STRING look for 2 variables and rewrite properly

Tags: .htaccess

I have an .htaccess file that works well. It does a silent redirect to another website. For one specific page, I need to look for one additional parameter in the query string and pass that to the site. Not sure how to do it....here is my file so far:

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^ajax/(.*)$ http://final.site.com/ajax/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteRule ^includes/(.*)$ http://final.site.com/includes/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteRule ^themes/(.*)$ http://final.site.com/themes/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ http://final.site.com/css/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ http://final.site.com/js/$1 [P,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myusername.site.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
    RewriteRule (.*) http://final\.site\.com/?username=myusername&page_name=Home [P,L]

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page_name=(.*) [NC]
    RewriteCond %1 !=get_some_kind_of_data [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) http://final\.site\.com/?username=myusername&page_name=%1 [P,L]
```

So I just want to add this...if I go to http://myusername.com/?page_name=All%20Art&collection_id=6, it should silently bring up http://final.site.com/?username=myusername&page_name=All%20Art&collection_id...and if the page_name is any thing else (except for "get_some_kind_of_data" shown above), there will be no collection_id passed.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the last rule with this:

```
# If page_name=get_some_kind_of_data, proxy everything in the query string along with username
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)?page_name=get_some_kind_of_data($|&)? [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://final.site.com/?username=myusername [P,L,QSA]

# If page_name exists but it isn't get_some_kind_of_data, match collection_id and remove it
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)?page_name=([^&]+)($|&)? [NC]
RewriteCond %1 !get_some_kind_of_data [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)(^|&)?collection_id=[0-9]+(.*)  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://final.site.com/?username=myusername&%1%3  [P,L]
```

So a request for:

> http://myusername.com/?foo=bar&page_name=get_some_kind_of_data&collection_id=6  proxies to http://final.site.com/?username=myusername&foo=bar&page_name=get_some_kind_of_data&collection_id=6

And

> http://myusername.com/?foo=bar&page_name=get_something_else&collection_id=6  proxies to http://final.site.com/?username=myusername&foo=bar&page_name=get_something_else

Is that what you're looking for?